# Popup message in mac “ConnectionCachefld” will damage your computer

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma

when got message, I try to click ok and show in finder but I don't see the file name. And I also try to search for it but still cannot find it.
[image]

when got message, I try to click ok and show in finder but I don't see the file name. And I also try to search for it but still cannot find it.

Comment: related?: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252484798